# display data in table format when i click button

Tags: php, jquery, mysqli

I want display my data in table format.

The datas are displayed in
 the webpage but i want to display the data when i click the button (view user). I have tried a lot but can't get it to work. When i click my button(view user) the data display in the page.. Can any one please help me?

script code:

```
    <form method="post" action="">
      <h3 class="alert alert-info" align="center">WELCOME TO ADMIN HOME PAGE</h3>
      <div class="container">
        <button class="btn btn-info" name="button" id="user">View USER</button>
        <br />
        <div class="table-resposive" id="user_data">
        </div>  
      </div>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){  

  load_data();

  function load_data()
  {
    $.ajax({
      url:"fetch.php",
      method:"POST",
      success:function(data)
      {
        $('#user_data').html(data);
      }
    });
  }  
</script>
```

Comment: Did you checked your console your ajax response return any error or not.

Comment: no error.. the table data has been showed..but i only set the button which i have not used yet..i dont know how to display data when i click button..can you help me?

Comment: can you show what u getting in data of ajax sucess

Comment: why are you using post?

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
<script>

$(document).on("click","#user",function(){
    load_data();
});

  function load_data()
  {
    $.ajax({
      url:"fetch.php",
      method:"POST",
      success:function(data)
      {
        $('#user_data').html(data);
      }
    });
  }  

<script>
```

Comment: @NikhilVagela I really don't understan why method is post? Isn't he trying to fetch data? I am sure I am missing something..

Comment: My friend @Brainmaniac  does't matter your method is get or post matter is you get proper response or not.

Answer (score 0):

Give your form an id

i.e. ,

then create a java script that will hide this form onclick, and show data on the same click.

```
        $(".btn1").click(function(){
        $("#name_of_the_form").hide();
        $("#addinst").hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

To call the function when you click the button you can use this:

```
$("#user").click( function()
{
    $.ajax({
      url:"fetch.php",
      method:"POST",
      success:function(data)
      {
        $('#user_data').html(data);
      }
    });
});
```

or just this:

```
$("#user").click(load_data);
```